# Pandas MemoryError while pd.concat

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am using pandas to read csv's.

```
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(StringIO(f)), compression='gzip', dtype=str) for f in all_files)
final_df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
```

total rows in all_files is about 90,00,000 though each file is of smaller size.

When pd.concat runs it is failing citing `Memory Error`.

The system has 16 GB of RAM and 16 CPU's 2 GHZ each.Is the memory insufficent here?
Is there anything else i can do to remove MemoryError?

i read about chunksize etc but each file is small and that should not be a problem.How can `concat` be made memoryerror free?

This is the traceback.

```
final_df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
File "/home/jenkins/fsroot/workspace/ric-dev-sim-2/VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 1326, in concat
return op.get_result()
File "/home/jenkins/fsroot/workspace/ric-dev-sim-2/VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/merge.py", line 1517, in get_result
copy=self.copy)
File "/home/jenkins/fsroot/workspace/ric-dev-sim-2/VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4797, in concatenate_block_managers
placement=placement) for placement, join_units in concat_plan]
File "/home/jenkins/fsroot/workspace/ric-dev-sim-2/VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 4902, in concatenate_join_units
concat_values = _concat._concat_compat(to_concat, axis=concat_axis)
File "/home/jenkins/fsroot/workspace/ric-dev-sim-2/VENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/types/concat.py", line 165, in _concat_compat
return np.concatenate(to_concat, axis=axis)
MemoryError
```

df.info for 1 file is

```
dtype: object<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 12516 entries, 0 to 12515
Columns: 322 entries, #RIC to Reuters Classification Scheme.1
dtypes: object(322)
memory usage: 30.7+ MB
None
```

Comment: @WesMcKinney any suggestions???????

Comment: How many columns do you have? When I have a dataframe with around 38 million rows and around 50 columns in memory it takes more than 32GB of my RAM. I have 64GB and I can't do any merging operations operating on this dataframe since I'd run out of memory on any attempted merge.

Comment: Oh, not 90 million. I was confused by your strange digit grouping "90,00,000".

Comment: @Khris 9 million,322 columns...........wont it fit into 16 gb?

Comment: Anyway, I'm doing a similar thing, I read smaller csv files (typical size is around 100 MB) and add them together into one large dataframe. But I use the `append` function to add each new dataframe to the main dataframe. Have you tried that instead of `concat`?

Comment: @Khris i read at places that append is slower than concat!!!!!!!have u timed it?

Comment: @Khris i can try that thought...coz even i have 100 mb files which join up to form a df of 9 million.........can you share the code.....or some other optimisations you are doing

Comment: No special optimization, I'm just reading in my dataframes and append them one after another to the main dataframe, it's basically just a `for`-loop.

Comment: @vks, can you post an output of the following command: `print(df.dtypes); print(df.info())` for one of your files / DFs?

Comment: Seems to me that you're reading all your files a strings? Are they really all strings? How long are the strings?

Comment: @schlump they are stored in s3....so from there i am reading them as string.....

Comment: Yeha but is all data in all columns string only?   Usually pandas read_csv determines the dtype automatically, but you specified to use only strings. If there are some integer columns you could save memory by reading them as int.

Comment: @MaxU added df.info() to question for 1 file.there are around 300 such files

Comment: @vks, looking at your next question you would need at least 2*90GB = 180GB of RAM for 9M rows (90GB for the resulting DF plus list 90GB for list of DFs that you are concatenating) if you will use this approach.

Answer (score 2):

First of all don't use `dtype=str` parameter unless you really need it.

Looking at  [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379104/python-pandas-df-info) you would need at least 2*90GB = 180GB of RAM for 9M rows (90GB for the resulting DF plus list 90GB for list of DFs that you are concatenating) if you will use this approach:

Calculation `17.1GB / 1713078 * (9*10**6) / 1GB`:

```
In [18]: 17.1*1024**3/1713078*(9*10**6)/1024**3
Out[18]: 89.8382910760631
```

So you will have to process your data file-per-file and to save it to something that can work with such amount of data - i would use either HDF or database like MySQL / PostgreSQL / etc.:

```
fn = r'c:/tmp/test.h5'
store = pd.HDFStore(fn)

df = pd.DataFrame()
for f in all_file_names:
    x = pd.read_csv(f)
    # process `x` DF here
    store.append('df_key', df, data_columns=[<list_of_indexed_columns>], complib='blosc', complevel=5)

store.close()
```

Comment: mm that explains MemoryError.Thanx a lot....though i cant use this apporach as frames have to be processed in one go.....cant process it line by line