# Python Pandas df.info

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
Total files to Process :  100
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1713078 entries, 0 to 1713077
Columns: 322 entries, #RIC to Reuters Classification Scheme.1
dtypes: object(322)
memory usage: 17.1 GB
None
```

I created a dataframe from 100 csv files and above you have `df.info(memory_usage='deep')` for that.
It shows `17.1 GB`.
What exactly does it mean?
My mac has only 16 GB RAM....how am i able to process it ?
And how much can that increase upto....like what would be the upper limit for that.

Comment: Would be [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye i have 8 gb swap....so it could go upto 24 gb?

Answer (score 0):

pandas allow to work with very large csv files, even if those doesn't fit in memory, one way to do it is to read it by chunks :

```
reader = pd.read_csv(csv_filename, iterator=True, chunksize=1000)
```

where chunksize is the number of rows to process.

You can then iterate on the TextParser object returned, like :

```
for df in reader:
# process each data frame
    your_processing(df)
```

Depending on your processing, you even even use multiprocessing to speed up things.